# How to find the P-wave amplitudes from an ECG signal in LabView?

Tags: labview

I have an ECG signal generated using Simulate ECG VI from BioMedical Toolkit. I need the P-wave amplitudes from this signal. Using peak detection, I will get all the peaks and then I should write an algorithm to extract the P-wave peak. Doing this, I cannot be sure my algorithm will work for a signal which will represent a disease. I there a posibility to do this ?

Comment: What is your question?
The title suggest you need the P-wave algorithm, the body suggests you might want to look for test signals.

Comment: I need to find the amplitudes of P-waves from a generated ECG signal....I don't know exactly how to do this in the right way...

Comment: There are a million ways to do this: frequency domain analysis, time domain filtering, differential signal processing, power spectrum analysis, neural networks to name a few